# Reg Expression include word lists

Tags: javascript, regex

I have built this script from some research on the first larger-letter topic. What it does is allow a span class of first-letter to be applied to a specific class (the page title), and it's working pretty good - ie wrapping every first letter with the span class first-letter, which allows me to make the first letter of every word in the title larger using CSS (I already have capitilize turned on for the class via CSS). What I have been trying to accomplish is somehow adding a list of words, abbreviations, or other 3-4 letter terms to the Regular Expression so that any words inside this list would wrapped with a class of first-letter. Here is the code I have so far. I have searched for a solution, but RegEx's boggle my mind trying to figure them out. Thanks

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-title")
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\b([a-z])([a-  z]+)?\b/gim, "<span class='first-letter'>$1</span>$2")
    }
```

Here is a fiddle I have started http://jsfiddle.net/5Sgve/38/

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of words, abbr `words = ["share", "link" ... ]`, you get a regex like this `regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z])(" + words.join("|") + ")", "gi");`

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Sgve/

Comment: I have been playing with the Fiddle you made, but can't get this to work. I started a Fiddle above with an example of how it needs to work. Basically the MD & FN-P would be the words in the list. Whatever words / abbreviations that are inside that list would all be RED & LARGER. (ie. have a span class of first-letter around them). I don't want any - / *, or other characters to get the first-letter class, just actual letters. (ie. A-Z, a-z). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it working. Thanks for the help! Here is the updated Fiddle for anyone interested in accomplishing this.

@ jsfiddle.net/5Sgve/421/

Comment: It doesn't look like it's actually using the array? http://jsfiddle.net/5Sgve/422/